# Kibana/Grafana-like UI for status display

Tags: logstash, kibana, grafana, statsd

I have several monitors which check how many lines were added to each database, and the status of the database (is it down or OK).

I use Kibana and Logstash (and sometimes Grafana and StatsD) to monitor the daily changes of the databases, but I still haven't found a UI suitable for displaying statuses, like the ones I described. So far, I use Kibana to display the change of the status over time, but that's not what I want.

Is there a UI or plugin that can suit my need? Hopefully something that also reads from Logstash or StatsD, and if it can display the numerical changes over time too - even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [Grafana Singlestat Panel](http://docs.grafana.org/reference/singlestat/). It allows you to add a single number and sparkline (for historic trends) as well as changing it's color based on status (green, amber, red etc).

I think that will do what you want.

Comment: Awesome, that's what I was looking for.. can't believe it was right there all along :)